# Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" that could not be resolved

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am working with WinForm App targeting net461 framework.
Unfortunately, this warning appeared in runtime error list :

*Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.*

[image: Found conflicts Error VS2017]

Adding to package.config does not helped :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Does anybody have an idea about this?

Comment: Did you look at the build log with the verbosity set to detail? You can probably fix this with a bindingredirect in your config file, but you're better off if you know what's going on

Comment: I created a new 4.6.1 winform project and can't replicate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem usually arises when different dependencies bring their own version of `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` assembly. It is true for any other assembly conflict as well.

The reason for such behavior lies in a faulty design of .NET Framework but also .NET Core dependency logic. The same warnings were quite often produced by .NET Core `coreclr` and `corefx` repo builds with only side effects being larger NuGet package containing all conflicting versions of assemblies and even complete frameworks.

The warning itself is benign and can be safely ignored. The only impact is that more packages will be imported by NuGet during the build.

Comment: Removing "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" from project references simply solved the problem.

Actually, "Diagnostics" is part of system namespace and I don't need to be specifically referencing it.

Thanks Jacek.

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem with duplicate framework references

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating from old-style to new-style `.csproj` files then the problem can come because of old `<runtime><assemblyBinding>` entries in the `App.config` file(s) of your project.

You can safely delete these sections. Then delete all NuGet caches (e.g. `C:\Users\{user}\.nuget` and `{project-dir}\packages`), then clean and rebuild.